# Converting .jrxml file to .pdf file

Tags: java, jasper-reports, ireport

I ran few load test on my web application.
Problem is the results of the load test application is in .jrxml format.
The result contains charts graphs and certain parameters.
I know its a jasperreport format.
So if I convert the .jrxml file to .pdf file will I be able to see all charts,graphs and values...

I am assuming irrespective of the .jrxml content about chart or graph the pdf generated will contain appropiate values as template is prepared according to the charting API.

Can I produce jasper report without specifying any datasource connection..I dont need a datasource connection since my .jrxml file does not contain a datasource attribute...
If yes, how can I acheive it..
Kindly suggest

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you don't have any data source, you can try this

```
jasperReport = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(sourceFileName);
jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport,jasperParameter,new  JREmptyDataSource()); 
JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdfFile(jasperPrint, "D://Test.pdf");
```

Even if you do not have any data source and its a static data report giving 
`JREmptyDataSource` is required.

Check the answer for more explanation

> [Blank PDF even with the simplest Jasperreport jrxml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5258307/blank-pdf-even-with-the-simplest-jasperreport-jrxml)

Comment: sir what if I have XML data source ? please help.

Answer (score 0):

.jrxml is  output of jasper designer When you compile it you obtain its parsed form .jasper .After that ,you populate this object with data ,parameter,variables and obtain  .print  object .And Finally, you can export this print object any format sopported by jasper report such as PDF,CVS,HTML,Excel ...

Comment: I already know those details..Possible problem will be whether without datasource can I generate a jasper report...I dont need a data source since my .jrxml file does not contain any datasource...The comment is bit deviated from the question I asked and I really apologise for this..

Answer (score 0):

If by "datasource connection" you mean a JDBC backed datasource, yes you can execute a report without requiring this.

There are other data source implementations that implement the **net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRDataSource** (for example **JRCsvDataSource**) that are "lighter-weight" than hitting a database - useful for testing.

**However for unit tests, I end up creating a mock implementation** of **JRDataSource** that implements **next()** and **getFieldValue()** and reads from a Collection of Map objects (this could instead read from a file, etc.).  This has been the simplest and fastest approach when it comes to testing for me.

Which part are you exactly load testing?  Usually the interesting parts to stress test are:

- Jasper report filling (executing the query, reading the results and filling a JasperPrint object)
- Jasper export (producing the report output format - HTML, PDF, XLS, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

If you are not using any data source then you have to select "Empty datasource" or "Sample datasource" from data sources if you are running sample reports, but as i think if you are crating a specific report for your project then u must have to select data source.