# Add sub reports to main report in Jasper Studio

Tags: jasper-reports, subreport

I have a XML which is to be converted to CSV format. I'm using Jasper Reports to convert it and using Jasper Studio to design the JRXML.

This is the XML :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<menu-compare xmlns:mig="http://www..com/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www..com">
    <menu-info>
        <menu type="ons" name="HCOTA"/>
        <menu type="ux" name="RTACOF"/>
    </menu-info>
    <field-details>
        <fields existence="both">
            <field name="taChrgOffMsg.taChrgOffCrit.funcCode">
                <field-type type="ons">
                    <group-name>cota</group-name>
                    <page-name>cotacrit</page-name>
                    <control-type>Combo Box</control-type>
                    <ui-field>funcCode</ui-field>
                    <label>FLT000204</label>
                    <label-desc>Function</label-desc>
                    <mandatory>Y</mandatory>
                </field-type>
                <field-type type="ux">
                    <group-name>Rtacof</group-name>
                    <page-name>Rtacof_criteria_form</page-name>
                    <page-name-desc>Transaction A/c. Details</page-name-desc>
                    <control-type>FinHidden</control-type>
                    <ui-field>funcCode</ui-field>
                    <section-structure>group1</section-structure>
                    <form>criteria</form>
                </field-type>
            </field>
            <field name="taChrgOffMsg.taChrgOffCrit.Acct.foracid">
                <field-type type="ons">
                    <group-name>cota</group-name>
                    <page-name>cotacrit</page-name>
                    <control-type>Text Field</control-type>
                    <ui-field>acctId</ui-field>
                    <label>FLT000265</label>
                    <label-desc>A/c. ID</label-desc>
                    <mandatory>Y</mandatory>
                </field-type>
                <field-type type="ux">
                    <group-name>Rtacof</group-name>
                    <page-name>Rtacof_criteria_form</page-name>
                    <page-name-desc>Transaction A/c. Details</page-name-desc>
                    <control-type>FinAccountId</control-type>
                    <ui-field>acctId$accountId</ui-field>
                    <label>FLT001251</label>
                    <label-desc>A/c. ID</label-desc>
                    <mandatory>Y</mandatory>
                    <section-structure>group1.section1.subSection1.finRow1.finCell1</section-structure>
                    <form>criteria</form>
                </field-type>
            </field>
        </fields>
        <fields existence="nonMap">
            <field>
                <field-type type="ons">
                    <group-name>cota</group-name>
                    <page-name>cotacrit</page-name>
                    <control-type>Desc. Label</control-type>
                    <ui-field>acctCrncy</ui-field>
                    <label></label>
                    <mandatory>N</mandatory>
                </field-type>
            </field>
            <field>
                <field-type type="ons">
                    <group-name>cota</group-name>
                    <page-name>cotacrit</page-name>
                    <control-type>Desc. Label</control-type>
                    <ui-field>acctSol</ui-field>
                    <label></label>
                    <mandatory>N</mandatory>
                </field-type>
            </field>
            <field>
                <field-type type="ons">
                    <group-name>cota</group-name>
                    <page-name>cotacrit</page-name>
                    <control-type>Desc. Label</control-type>
                    <ui-field>acctName</ui-field>
                    <label></label>
                    <mandatory>N</mandatory>
                </field-type>
            </field>
            <field>
                <field-type type="ux">
                    <group-name>Rtacof</group-name>
                    <page-name>Rtacof_criteria_form</page-name>
                    <page-name-desc>Transaction A/c. Details</page-name-desc>
                    <control-type>FinAccountId</control-type>
                    <ui-field>acctId</ui-field>
                    <label>FLT001251</label>
                    <label-desc>A/c. ID</label-desc>
                    <mandatory>Y</mandatory>
                    <section-structure>group1.section1.subSection1.finRow1.finCell1</section-structure>
                    <form>criteria</form>
                </field-type>
            </field>
            <field>
                <field-type type="ux">
                    <group-name>Rtacof</group-name>
                    <page-name>Rtacof_criteria_form</page-name>
                    <page-name-desc>Transaction A/c. Details</page-name-desc>
                    <control-type>FinHidden</control-type>
                    <ui-field>funcCodeExp</ui-field>
                    <section-structure>group1</section-structure>
                    <form>criteria</form>
                </field-type>
            </field>
            <field>
                <field-type type="ux">
                    <group-name>Rtacof</group-name>
                    <page-name>Rtacof_criteria_form</page-name>
                    <page-name-desc>Transaction A/c. Details</page-name-desc>
                    <control-type>FinHidden</control-type>
                    <ui-field>hchrgeOffAmt</ui-field>
                    <section-structure>group1</section-structure>
                    <form>criteria</form>
                </field-type>
            </field>
        </fields>
        <fields existence="ux">
            <field name="taChrgOffMsg.taChrgOffCrit.Acct.acctName">
                <field-type type="ux">
                    <group-name>Rtacof</group-name>
                    <page-name>Rtacof_criteria_form</page-name>
                    <page-name-desc>Transaction A/c. Details</page-name-desc>
                    <control-type>FinAccountId</control-type>
                    <ui-field>acctId$accountNameDesc</ui-field>
                    <label>FLT001251</label>
                    <label-desc>A/c. ID</label-desc>
                    <mandatory>Y</mandatory>
                    <section-structure>group1.section1.subSection1.finRow1.finCell1</section-structure>
                    <form>criteria</form>
                </field-type>
            </field>
            <field name="taChrgOffMsg.taChrgOffCrit.Acct.crncyCode">
                <field-type type="ux">
                    <group-name>Rtacof</group-name>
                    <page-name>Rtacof_criteria_form</page-name>
                    <page-name-desc>Transaction A/c. Details</page-name-desc>
                    <control-type>FinAccountId</control-type>
                    <ui-field>acctId$currencyDesc</ui-field>
                    <label>FLT001251</label>
                    <label-desc>A/c. ID</label-desc>
                    <mandatory>Y</mandatory>
                    <section-structure>group1.section1.subSection1.finRow1.finCell1</section-structure>
                    <form>criteria</form>
                </field-type>
            </field>
        </fields>
    </field-details>
</menu-compare>
```

I want the CSV format with the below columns :

```
                                    ons(field_type)        ux(field_type)
     fields_existence field_name control-type page-name control-type page-name
```

fields_exitence is split into 3(nonMap, ux and both), 
properties under `<field-type type="ons">` need to fall under a merged cell 'ons', `<field-type type="ux">` need to fall under a merged cell 'ux' as above.

So i've created a main report which will have the `fields_existence` and `field_name` and two subreports for 'ons' and 'ux'.

main report :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Created with Jaspersoft Studio version last-->
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="New3" language="groovy" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" uuid="7eade40b-45a9-4626-bef7-fbcc2d4397a4">
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.defaultdataadapter" value="New Data Adapter (5)"/>
    <subDataset name="Dataset1" uuid="5c92bcef-d33d-481e-afaa-02aa04792e45">
        <queryString>
            <![CDATA[]]>
        </queryString>
        <field name="field_name" class="java.lang.String">
            <fieldDescription><![CDATA[@name]]></fieldDescription>
        </field>
        <field name="control-type-ons" class="java.lang.String">
            <fieldDescription><![CDATA[/fields/field/field-type[@type = "ons"]/control-type]]></fieldDescription>
        </field>
        <field name="control-type-ux" class="java.lang.String">
            <fieldDescription><![CDATA[/fields/field/field-type[@type = "ux"]/control-type]]></fieldDescription>
        </field>
        <field name="control-typee-ons" class="java.lang.String">
            <fieldDescription><![CDATA[control-type]]></fieldDescription>
        </field>
        <field name="control-typee-ux" class="java.lang.String">
            <fieldDescription><![CDATA[/fields/field/field-type[@type = "ux"]/control-type]]></fieldDescription>
        </field>
        <field name="label-desc-ons" class="java.lang.String">
            <fieldDescription><![CDATA[/fields/field/field-type[@type = "ons"]/label-desc]]></fieldDescription>
        </field>
    </subDataset>
    <subDataset name="Dataset2" uuid="f8c00177-6263-49fc-b17d-f307080a8539">
        <queryString>
            <![CDATA[]]>
        </queryString>
        <field name="control-type_d2_ons" class="java.lang.String">
            <fieldDescription><![CDATA[control-type]]></fieldDescription>
        </field>
    </subDataset>
    <queryString language="XPath">
        <![CDATA[/menu-compare/field-details/fields]]>
    </queryString>
    <field name="fields_exists" class="java.lang.String">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[@existence]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="field" class="java.lang.String">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[field]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="field_1" class="java.lang.String">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[field]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="field_2" class="java.lang.String">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[field]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="field_3" class="java.lang.String">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[field]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="field_4" class="java.lang.String">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[field]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="field_5" class="java.lang.String">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[field]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <background>
        <band splitType="Stretch"/>
    </background>
    <title>
        <band height="79" splitType="Stretch"/>
    </title>
    <pageHeader>
        <band height="35" splitType="Stretch"/>
    </pageHeader>
    <columnHeader>
        <band height="73" splitType="Stretch">
            <textField>
                <reportElement uuid="a7807abf-6697-4dbb-b990-f4a63572c158" x="10" y="30" width="70" height="30"/>
                <textElement/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["Map_Type"]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement uuid="fe9d6fa6-30c2-4507-867a-f60d872a4002" x="110" y="30" width="70" height="30"/>
                <textElement/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["Field-Name"]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </columnHeader>
    <detail>
        <band height="264" splitType="Stretch">
            <textField>
                <reportElement uuid="3f1e6c53-cb80-4117-9aeb-c5b26b1169c0" x="10" y="10" width="70" height="30"/>
                <textElement/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{fields_exists}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <componentElement>
                <reportElement uuid="e888d323-d870-4c8d-9826-2930dbafcaa4" x="100" y="10" width="310" height="60"/>
                <jr:list xmlns:jr="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/components.xsd" printOrder="Vertical">
                    <datasetRun subDataset="Dataset1" uuid="fba9150e-05b0-4c8d-933f-26e4766a1de4">
                        <dataSourceExpression><![CDATA[$P{REPORT_DATA_SOURCE}.subDataSource("/fields/field")]]></dataSourceExpression>
                    </datasetRun>
                    <jr:listContents height="66" width="310">
                        <textField>
                            <reportElement uuid="6fb1b0ce-65f2-4c22-aa27-f4083bb535c2" x="10" y="15" width="70" height="30"/>
                            <textElement/>
                            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{field_name}]]></textFieldExpression>
                        </textField>
                        <textField>
                            <reportElement uuid="c1821c08-9cdd-4ab2-81d1-6e7981f755fe" x="100" y="15" width="70" height="30"/>
                            <textElement/>
                            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{control-type-ons}]]></textFieldExpression>
                        </textField>
                        <textField>
                            <reportElement uuid="c5cd28df-0742-4f4b-ae5d-1098b472b5a0" x="200" y="15" width="70" height="30"/>
                            <textElement/>
                            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{control-type-ux}]]></textFieldExpression>
                        </textField>
                    </jr:listContents>
                </jr:list>
            </componentElement>
            <subreport>
                <reportElement uuid="e57583f2-7163-4c8b-8245-7586cf22491f" x="440" y="20" width="41" height="46"/>
                <dataSourceExpression><![CDATA[$P{REPORT_DATA_SOURCE}.subDataSource("/fields/field/field-type")]]></dataSourceExpression>
                <subreportExpression><![CDATA["New3_SubReport_Ons.jasper"]]></subreportExpression>
            </subreport>
        </band>
    </detail>
    <columnFooter>
        <band height="45" splitType="Stretch"/>
    </columnFooter>
    <pageFooter>
        <band height="54" splitType="Stretch"/>
    </pageFooter>
    <summary>
        <band height="42" splitType="Stretch"/>
    </summary>
</jasperReport>
```

SubReport_ONS : Here i get the data properly, all the field properties listed under   are populated. But when i add it to the main report nothing is getting populated.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Created with Jaspersoft Studio version last-->
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="New3_SubReport_Ons" language="groovy" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" uuid="7d9c4551-de86-4504-9dc0-b7617a01f620">
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.defaultdataadapter" value="New Data Adapter (5)"/>
    <queryString language="xPath">
        <![CDATA[/menu-compare/field-details/fields/field/field-type[@type = "ons"]]]>
    </queryString>
    <field name="group-name" class="java.lang.String">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[group-name]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="page-name" class="java.lang.String">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[page-name]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="control-type" class="java.lang.String">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[control-type]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="ui-field" class="java.lang.String">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[ui-field]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="label" class="java.lang.String">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[label]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="label-desc" class="java.lang.String">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[label-desc]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="mandatory" class="java.lang.String">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[mandatory]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="section-structure" class="java.lang.String">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[section-structure]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="form" class="java.lang.String">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[form]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <background>
        <band splitType="Stretch"/>
    </background>
    <columnHeader>
        <band height="74" splitType="Stretch">
            <textField>
                <reportElement uuid="11e36190-331d-492d-b2f8-b6b5e255ad29" x="0" y="30" width="70" height="30"/>
                <textElement/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["control-type"]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement uuid="d29aaacd-1eb0-4f18-800f-79745afaab6a" x="80" y="30" width="70" height="30"/>
                <textElement/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["label-desc"]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement uuid="975c7937-8450-4270-a14c-f04906402a8a" x="160" y="30" width="70" height="30"/>
                <textElement/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["label"]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement uuid="29fd8188-114b-4731-8b44-e1b8b87b5734" x="242" y="30" width="70" height="30"/>
                <textElement/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["ui-field"]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement uuid="8f51cdc4-c1ce-4337-ab61-f4d43d4646bc" x="320" y="30" width="70" height="30"/>
                <textElement/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["group-name"]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement uuid="7f31617e-3683-4693-a248-6bebe0f5bdf5" x="400" y="30" width="70" height="30"/>
                <textElement/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["page-name"]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement uuid="24846d3e-7179-4fc7-91e2-f087b35676ac" x="490" y="30" width="70" height="30"/>
                <textElement/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["mandatory"]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </columnHeader>
    <detail>
        <band height="125" splitType="Stretch">
            <textField>
                <reportElement uuid="24c09848-f19d-4954-94d9-f6b1cb95f968" x="0" y="20" width="70" height="30"/>
                <textElement/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{control-type}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement uuid="ab6c2cb7-8591-46e4-900e-4b60e0f08f21" x="80" y="20" width="70" height="30"/>
                <textElement/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{label-desc}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement uuid="ab1ff84a-23b9-44c1-88a6-1c5a9fffaeb5" x="160" y="20" width="70" height="30"/>
                <textElement/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{label}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement uuid="acfb12b3-d8e0-4319-9339-182ac90a5e8b" x="242" y="20" width="70" height="30"/>
                <textElement/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{ui-field}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement uuid="1e0c29fd-e910-40dc-b67b-57aabcf96726" x="320" y="20" width="70" height="30"/>
                <textElement/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{group-name}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement uuid="f37a62d2-2dfe-4f97-b60e-6fc2cf7e868c" x="400" y="20" width="70" height="30"/>
                <textElement/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{page-name}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement uuid="084363d8-635f-4d8b-b0d2-01dbca4ff39f" x="490" y="20" width="70" height="30"/>
                <textElement/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{mandatory}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </detail>
</jasperReport>
```

Comment: Your problem is a classic. You should have done a better search. You may find your answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5258307/blank-pdf-even-with-the-simplest-jasperreport-jrxml/5334415#5334415

Answer (score 0):

Try to publish your reports on the JasperReports Server then run the main report ....
The main idea is the JasperSoft Studio did not give us a precise execution of reports, some topics must be implemented and executed in the JasperReports Server to check the successes or the wrong of our work ...
I hope it helped you, best regards.