# Jasper Report Generate Empty .PDF

Tags: java, jasper-reports, jsf-2.2

i try to create an application that generate a PDF report using Jasper Report 5.6.0, after some research and also watching a youtube tutorial, i found a problem: the Tutorial Succeed to Generate the PDF File, but i cannot, it only show empty PDF :(

PS: The Static Text Also not showing

JasperController.java

```
@Named(value = "jasperController")
@Dependent
public class JasperController {
    @EJB
    PelangganFacade pf;
    List<Pelanggan> plg;
    JasperPrint jasperPrint;

    public List<Pelanggan> getPelanggan() {
        plg = pf.findAll();
        return plg;
    }

    public void setPelanggan(List<Pelanggan> pelanggan) {
        this.plg = pelanggan;
    }

    public void init() throws JRException {
        JRBeanCollectionDataSource datasource = new JRBeanCollectionDataSource(plg);
        String reportPath = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext()
            .getRealPath("WEB-INF/Blank_A4.jasper");

        jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(reportPath, new HashMap(), datasource);
    }

    public void createPDF() throws JRException, IOException {
        init();
        HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getResponse();
        response.addHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment; filename=report.pdf");

        ServletOutputStream outputStream = response.getOutputStream();
        JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdfStream(jasperPrint, outputStream);
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().responseComplete();
    }
}
```

JSF Faces

```
<h:form>
    <h:commandButton value="Export PDF" action="#{jasperController.createPDF()}" />
</h:form>
```

Part of Pelanggan.java (to let you know the Field name)

```
public class Pelanggan implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "idPelanggan")
    private Integer idPelanggan;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 1, max = 45)
    @Column(name = "nama")
    private String nama;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 1, max = 45)
    @Column(name = "perusahaan")
    private String perusahaan;
    // @Pattern(regexp="[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*@(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?", message="Invalid email")//if the field contains email address consider using this annotation to enforce field validation
    @Size(max = 45)
    @Column(name = "email")
    private String email;
    @Size(max = 45)
    @Column(name = "telp")
    private String telp;
    @Size(max = 45)
    @Column(name = "hape")
    private String hape;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 1, max = 45)
    @Column(name = "alamat")
    private String alamat;
```

Blank_A4.jrxml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Created with Jaspersoft Studio version last-->
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="Blank_A4" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" uuid="b86c8877-f14d-4642-bf2b-910096217a3a">
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.defaultdataadapter" value="TestHar"/>
    <queryString>
        <![CDATA[SELECT * FROM Pelanggan]]>
    </queryString>
    <field name="nama" class="java.lang.String">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="perusahaan" class="java.lang.String">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="email" class="java.lang.String">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="telp" class="java.lang.String">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="hape" class="java.lang.String">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="alamat" class="java.lang.String">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <group name="nama">
        <groupExpression><![CDATA[$F{nama}]]></groupExpression>
    </group>
    <group name="perusahaan">
        <groupExpression><![CDATA[$F{perusahaan}]]></groupExpression>
    </group>
    <group name="email">
        <groupExpression><![CDATA[$F{email}]]></groupExpression>
    </group>
    <group name="telp">
        <groupExpression><![CDATA[$F{telp}]]></groupExpression>
    </group>
    <group name="hape">
        <groupExpression><![CDATA[$F{hape}]]></groupExpression>
    </group>
    <group name="alamat">
        <groupExpression><![CDATA[$F{alamat}]]></groupExpression>
    </group>
    <background>
        <band splitType="Stretch"/>
    </background>
    <title>
        <band height="79" splitType="Stretch">
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="555" height="79" uuid="7bc22187-5b7a-48b9-8b6c-663442314045"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font fontName="Arial" size="26" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Static Text]]></text>
            </staticText>
        </band>
    </title>
    <pageHeader>
        <band height="35" splitType="Stretch"/>
    </pageHeader>
    <columnHeader>
        <band height="61" splitType="Stretch">
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="0" y="40" width="100" height="20" uuid="4c0c57c6-f434-429f-bc89-2c3a69364f1e"/>
                <text><![CDATA[nama]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="450" y="40" width="100" height="20" uuid="2cd50524-bfec-4dbf-8bb4-7b199c8dcc14"/>
                <text><![CDATA[alamat]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="100" y="40" width="100" height="20" uuid="4cae3344-b6f0-484e-9155-67c5e65b17ba"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Left">
                    <font isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[PERUSAHAAN]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="350" y="40" width="100" height="20" uuid="4d24ba31-12f9-4972-b861-26e88172a717"/>
                <text><![CDATA[telp]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="200" y="40" width="130" height="20" uuid="63ee6043-0ecc-4249-99b2-523e39a7ffea"/>
                <text><![CDATA[Email]]></text>
            </staticText>
        </band>
    </columnHeader>
    <detail>
        <band height="34" splitType="Stretch">
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="-1" y="0" width="100" height="20" uuid="65ae19c3-dc06-45e8-95b1-c0e00289329b"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{nama}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="450" y="0" width="100" height="20" uuid="6ec9762d-3a2c-438f-a397-4e7ede9c9c6b"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{alamat}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="100" y="0" width="100" height="20" uuid="13856c00-f231-4170-93af-f01a0a02997c"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{perusahaan}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="350" y="0" width="100" height="20" uuid="81f072ad-c0ce-490d-b380-c2c1b4c37c31"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{telp}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="200" y="0" width="130" height="20" uuid="63148423-b08b-4937-b586-904a82397b88"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{email}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </detail>
    <columnFooter>
        <band splitType="Stretch"/>
    </columnFooter>
    <pageFooter>
        <band splitType="Stretch"/>
    </pageFooter>
    <summary>
        <band splitType="Stretch"/>
    </summary>
</jasperReport>
```

Debugging:
[image: Screenshot 1]

yes i know, it have null object (empty)
then i try to change some code so the object not empty

[image: screenshot 2]

now it shows error message:
[image]

Comment: `Blank_A4.jasper` - let me guess - you getting blank A4 pdf ?

Comment: yes, it's only a name, i have fill the report using Jaspersoft Studio with the field, but i saved it as Blank_A4.jasper filename http://postimg.org/image/yj2bx9u4t/ but it shows only white PDF

Comment: Do you have subreports? Are you setting a data source and a non-null query for it? Maybe this can help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5258307/blank-pdf-even-with-the-simplest-jasperreport-jrxml/5334415#5334415

Comment: Did you passes atleast one object in list. Also post your jrxml code for better understanding.

Comment: Is there any particular reason why you've opted for a `@Dependent` scope?

Comment: No, actually netbeans generate it by default... Should i change it?

Comment: Show more stacktrace. At one of next string of stacktrace must present field, which generate exception. And show getter for this field.

Comment: Maybe the problem is that jasper do require a data source to show the detail band. take a look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56507099/2768318